# How to Execute .cypher file using Neo4j 3.1.4 (Not Through .zip File)

Tags: shell, command-line, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm new to Neo4j and I have imported data from csv files using the browser console. I've downloaded Neo4j and went through the installation not using the .zip file which contains many tools such as neo4j-shell.bat and neo4j-admin.bat.

How can I execute multiple queries which I've made into .cypher file?
I can't seem to find the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe **cypher-shell.bat** is part of the Windows CE EXE installation. You can run cypher scripts with that.

Check https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/cypher-shell/ for more details.

Hope this helps,
Tom

Comment: I've read those.
What I need is basically the Windows version of this command

"cat examples.cypher | bin/cypher-shell -u neo4j -p secret --format plain"

Or I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: What about "type examples.cypher | bin\cypher-shell.bat -u neo4j -p secret" ?

Comment: WOW, it worked!!!
Thank you very much Tom!!

Do you happen to know how to print the progress of the script?
I put the command "USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000", but it's not printing anything on the command prompt.

Comment: There's no immediate way to see the progress (as far as I know). However, while running the script you can do - for example - a count of the created nodes (or whatever it is you are changing) in a browser session. That count should change every time a commit kicks in. Glad to have been of help !

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why "type" and "cat"?  I can't seem to find any info on what that is/how it works.